# Understanding vba scripting dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have collected a vba code from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/please-need-to-find-common-values-among-multiple-columns.915008/), as below, snippet from googling that identifies common cell value among multiple columns and places those common values to a separate columns.

```
Sub get_common_value_from_multiple_columns()

Dim a, c As Long, j As Long, e
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set a = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
c = a.Columns.Count
a.Select

For j = 0 To c - 1:
    For Each e In a.Columns(j + 1).Value
        If d(e) = j _
            Then d(e) = j + 1
    Next e, j

For Each e In d
    If d(e) < j _
        Then d.Remove e
Next e

If d.Count > 0 _
    Then Cells(c + 1).Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub
```

But I am not able to understand some of that sub procedure as highlighted in the below image-
[image]

Please help to understand what that highlighted codes are doing?

---

### EDIT

After getting some comment I have re-written the sub procedure anew as below-

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub get_common_value_from_multiple_columns()

    Dim data_dictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Dim data_dictionary As Object
    'Set data_dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim columns_count As Long
    Dim iterator As Integer
    Dim dictionary_item As Variant
    Dim selected_cells As Variant
    
    Set selected_cells = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    columns_count = selected_cells.Columns.Count
    selected_cells.Select
    
    'Populate the dictionary defined earlier
    For iterator = 0 To columns_count - 1:
        For Each dictionary_item In selected_cells.Columns(iterator + 1).Value
            Debug.Print data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = iterator, dictionary_item
            If data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = iterator Then
                data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = iterator + 1
            End If
        Next dictionary_item
    Next iterator
    
    'Remove the unique values
    For Each dictionary_item In data_dictionary
        If data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) < iterator Then
            data_dictionary.Remove dictionary_item
        End If
    Next dictionary_item
    
    'Copy the common value to a new columns
    If data_dictionary.Count > 0 Then
        Cells(columns_count + 2).Resize(data_dictionary.Count) = Application.Transpose(data_dictionary.Keys)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

But nonetheless I am not understanding the lines as below how If condition gets True or False-

```
    If data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = iterator Then
        data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = iterator + 1
```

for the first column that If gets True and for the second column of excel it gets False but how?

Comment: If you are learning then it is better to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting runtime so that you can use en early bound reference to scripting dictionaries and also get b the benefit of intellisense.

Comment: This is the source of code `https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/please-need-to-find-common-values-among-multiple-columns.915008/`

Comment: I am sort of learning stage of VBA. At the first run how `d(e) = j` gets TRUE while nothing assigned before? and what `d(e) < j` does?

Comment: You are correct to query the If data_dictionary.Item lines.  Where in your code is your dictionary populated with data because in both your current and previous examples your first use of the dictionary to test against iterator is done when there is no data in the dictionary.  So what do you think is going to happen? Perhaps you can edit your question to explain the task for which you are using your dictionary, then it might be possible to give you some better info.

Comment: Could you explain what *common values* means in this case? Does it mean *a value that occurs at least once in each of the columns*? If so, you could e.g. write the unique values of the first column to the `Keys` of a dictionary with `Value = 1`, then loop through the cells of each next column and only add `1` to the `Value` of an existing `Key` (be careful if duplicates). Finally, remove the `Keys` that do not have `Value = NumberOfColumns` and write the remaining `Keys` to a 2D one-based one-column array (avoid `Transpose` due to its limitations), and write the values of the array to a range.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the way above function works. No one answers after many hours passed. Finally I ended up in a different solution as below-

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub get_common_value_from_multiple_columns()

    Dim data_dictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Dim data_dictionary As Object
    'Set data_dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim columns_count As Long
    Dim iterator As Integer
    Dim dictionary_item As Variant
    Dim selected_cells As Variant
    
    Set selected_cells = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    columns_count = selected_cells.Columns.Count
    selected_cells.Select
    
    'Populate the dictionary defined earlier
    For iterator = 0 To columns_count - 1:
        For Each dictionary_item In selected_cells.Columns(iterator + 1).Value
            If Not data_dictionary.Exists(dictionary_item) Then
                data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = 1
            ElseIf data_dictionary.Exists(dictionary_item) Then
                data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) = data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) + 1
            End If
        Next dictionary_item
    Next iterator
    
    'Remove the unique values
    For Each dictionary_item In data_dictionary
        If data_dictionary.Item(dictionary_item) < iterator Then
            data_dictionary.Remove dictionary_item
        End If
    Next dictionary_item
    
    'Copy the common value to a new columns
    If data_dictionary.Count > 0 Then
        Cells(columns_count + 2).Resize(data_dictionary.Count) = Application.Transpose(data_dictionary.Keys)
    End If
    
End Sub
```